# Rails 4 multiple file attachments with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-4, model, paperclip

I'm aware that there are several posts on Stackoverflow and several tutorials about this subject. None of them however manage to solve my issue and most of them are outdated as well.

I am trying to add multiple images to a project using the paperclip gem in Rails 4.
When i try uploading it i do see the asset attached in the params.

They do not seem to be added to the project_paramns though..

Hope someone can help me out here.

**This is my projects_controller**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :find_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
   @projects = Project.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    @project.save

    redirect_to project_path(@project)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @project.update(project_params)

    redirect_to project_path(@project)
  end

  def destroy
    @project.destroy

    redirect_to projects_path
  end

  protected

    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, :asset)
    end

    def find_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

**My project model**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assets, :dependent => :destroy

  validates_associated :assets
  validates_presence_of :name, :on => :create, :update => "can't be blank"
  validates_presence_of :description, :on => :create, :update => "can't be blank"

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets
end
```

**My asset model**

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project

  # Paperclip
  has_attached_file :image,
    :styles => {
      :thumb=> "100x100#",
      :small  => "150x150>",
      :medium => "300x300>",
      :large =>   "400x400>" }
  validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg",     "image/png", "image/gif"] }
end
```

**And my form partial (Sorry it's in HAML)**

```
= simple_form_for @project do |f|
  %ul
    - @project.errors.full_messages.each do |error|
      %li= error
  .row
    .small-1.columns    
      = f.label :name, :class => "left inline"
    .small-11.columns
      = f.input_field :name
  .row
    .small-1.columns
      = f.label :description, :class => "left inline"
    .small-11.columns 
      = f.input_field :description, as: :text
  .row
    = f.simple_fields_for :asset do |a|
      .small-1.columns
        = a.label :image, :class => "left inline"
      .small-11.columns
        = file_field_tag :image, multiple: true,
  .row
    .small-9.small-offset-1.columns
      = f.submit nil ,:class => "button [radius round]"
```

**Request Parameters**

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"4iK1kUNvKvoJVOKoivz/pcLAe6LY0cUJikQioxa8BIs=", "project"=>{"name"=>"adf", "description"=>"adf", "asset"=>{"image"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fb808357d80 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/v_/98sxm8bn24qbqj_jmj40fv400000gn/T/RackMultipart20140607-34739-dvlzt7>, @original_filename="enabling-gzip-compression.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"project[asset][image][]\"; filename=\"enabling-gzip-compression.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fb808357d58 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/v_/98sxm8bn24qbqj_jmj40fv400000gn/T/RackMultipart20140607-34739-lwkioi>, @original_filename="minimize_http_requests.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"project[asset][image][]\"; filename=\"minimize_http_requests.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">]}}, "commit"=>"Update Project", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"projects", "id"=>"11"}
```

**Now i've also got an error showing up in my terminal:**

```
Unpermitted parameters: asset
```

**Edit:**

A combination of @pavan's and @kiri thorat's answers have helped me get something showing up in project_params, the output it gives now is:

```
{"name"=>"Test", "description"=>"Test", "assets_attributes"=>{"0"=>{}}}
```

Any clue on what's going on here?

After @kirithorat's latest update things seem to be good on the parameter side of things.

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"4iK1kUNvKvoJVOKoivz/pcLAe6LY0cUJikQioxa8BIs=", "project"=>{"name"=>"Test", "description"=>"Test", "assets_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fcd383c9a08 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/v_/98sxm8bn24qbqj_jmj40fv400000gn/T/RackMultipart20140610-36517-7ek1oq>, @original_filename="enabling-gzip-compression.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"project[assets_attributes][0][image]\"; filename=\"enabling-gzip-compression.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}}}, "commit"=>"Update Project", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"projects", "id"=>"13"}
```

The assets are still not being saved though.

**Update after implementing @Valikiliy's suggestions**

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"4iK1kUNvKvoJVOKoivz/pcLAe6LY0cUJikQioxa8BIs=", "project"=>{"name"=>"Test", "description"=>"Test", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fcd3a08d0b8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/v_/98sxm8bn24qbqj_jmj40fv400000gn/T/RackMultipart20140610-36517-rgy95n>, @original_filename="minimize_http_requests.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"project[image]\"; filename=\"minimize_http_requests.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Update Project", "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"projects", "id"=>"16"}
```

**Update: Added new form code on request**

```
= simple_form_for(@project, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
  %ul
    - @project.errors.full_messages.each do |error|
      %li= error
  .row
    .small-1.columns    
      = f.label :name, :class => "left inline"
    .small-11.columns
      = f.text_field :name
  .row
    .small-1.columns
      = f.label :description, :class => "left inline"
    .small-11.columns 
      = f.text_area :description
  .row
    = f.simple_fields_for :assets do |a|
      .small-1.columns
        = a.label :image, :class => "left inline"
      .small-11.columns
        - if a.object.new_record?
          = a.input :image, as: :file
        - else
          = image_tag a.object.image.url(:thumb)
          = a.input_field '_destroy', as: :boolean
  .row
    .small-9.small-offset-1.columns
      = f.submit nil ,:class => "button [radius round]"
```

**Update**

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, images: [], assets_attributes: [:_destroy, :id, :image])
end

def find_project
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @project.assets.build if %w[new edit].include?(action_name) 
end
```

**Update: Added model code**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assets, :dependent => :destroy

  validates_presence_of :name, :on => :create, :update => "can't be blank"
  validates_presence_of :description, :on => :create, :update => "can't be blank"

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To save multiple files in the above example you, do not need add **multiple: true** option, it will cause an error when saving, **one file - one record** assets table.

For resolve this, you can add multiple file fields, like this:
add into controller:

```
def new
  @project = Project.new
  3.times{ @project.assets.build } 
end

def edit
  3.times{ @project.assets.build } 
end
```

for while list

```
.permit(..., assets_attributes: [ :_destroy, :id, :image ])
```

and in view like this:

```
= f.simple_fields_for :assets do |a|
  .small-1.columns
    = a.label :image, :class => "left inline"
    - if a.object.new_record?
      .small-11.columns
        = a.file_field :image
    - else
      .small-11.columns
        = image_tag a.object.image.url(:thumb)
        = a.input_field '_destroy', as: :boolean
```

If you try to send multiple images like this:

```
# view
a.file_field :image, multiple: true

# controller
.permit(..., assets_attributes: [ :_destroy, :id, image: [] ])
```

This will cause an error because the Asset model does not know what to do with an array of images.

To save more than one file at the same time, you need to use your own handler, for example:

model: add the `images=` method

```
def images=(files = [])
  assets.create(image: f)
end
```

controller: move `images: []` outside of the assets_attributes

```
.permit(..., images: [], assets_attributes: [ :_destroy, :id ])
```

view: remove the fields_for and nested attributes

```
  .row
    .small-1.columns
      =f.file_field :images, multiple: true
  .row
    = f.simple_fields_for :assets do |a|
      .small-1.columns
        = a.label :image, :class => "left inline"
....
```

Comment: Thanks you for the the detailed response @Vakiliy. Saving multiple images into a single asset is indeed not the smartest thing i've tried to do.

I tried your solutions and even though they seem to be valid i still have a problem i should deal with first.

Somehow assets never get saved. Do you see anything in my code that could be the cause of this?

Comment: I have implemented the changes in Update 1 and it's still not saving assets. :(

Comment: Show You log After post form.

Comment: Posted in the original question

Comment: Show You form code, because the submitted data do not correspond to what should be.

Comment: Added it to the original question.

Comment: This form its work, and data processed. Show You controller code after protected.

Comment: Added it to the original question.

Comment: All right, only remove the 'images:' from params.require after 'desription'. Form not send images data directly. And show You model, because it latest  what remains to check.

Comment: Remove :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, form not send field `content` and images deleted from associated array. 
also add @project.assets.build into 'new' and 'edit' method, and remove @project.assets.build if %w[new edit].include?(action_name). and try again! :)

Comment: I want to give you the bounty but Stackoverflow is telling me it's possible in 36 minutes. I'll make sure to award it then :)

Answer (score 4):

You have 1-M relationship between `Project` and `Asset` models i.e.,

*Project has_many assets*

so, in your form partial `simple_fields_for` should look like

```
= f.simple_fields_for :assets do |a|
```

**Notice** `assets` in *plural* and NOT `asset` in *singular*

In your current code, you used `simple_fields_for` with *singular* `asset` which is why your `params` is generated incorrectly and you receive `asset` key in `params` hash instead of receiving `assets_attributes` key which results in the warning as `Unpermitted parameters: asset`.

Once you correct the form partial you would receive the correct keys in `params` hash upon form submission. Now, as @Pavan pointed out next problem that I see is you have not permitted the `assets_attributes` correctly in the controller.

You need to update the `project_params` method as below:

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, assets_attributes: [:image])
end
```

**Notice** `assets_attributes` with `assets` in *plural*

**UPDATE**

You would need to add `@project.assets.build` in `new` and `edit` action of `ProjectsController` in order to see the fields for assets in the `new` and `edit` view.
Also, I would suggest adding `:id` in the list of permitted attributes for `assets_attributes` in `project_params` as below:

```
  params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, assets_attributes: [:id, :image])
```

Few more problems that I see is in the `form partial` are

1. As you are uploading a file, you should specify `:html => {:multipart => true}` in the form.

   Change

   ```
   = simple_form_for @project do |f|
   ```

   To

   ```
   = simple_form_for @project, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
   ```
2. *Project has_many assets* and every `asset` record would have only one `image`, so remove `multiple: true`. Also, as you are using `simple_form`, its advisable to use `simple_form` helper method for uploading file.

   Change

   ```
   = file_field_tag :image, multiple: true,
   ```

   To

   ```
   = a.input :image, as: :file
   ```

Comment: Thank you kiri, when i changed it to assets initially the file field didn't show. After including @project.assets.build in my new and edit actions however it shows the field.

My project params now includes this: {"name"=>"Test", "description"=>"Test", "assets_attributes"=>{"0"=>{}}}

So at least assets is showing up:)
The image is however not saving yet, any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: Good catch on plural(assets) thing. I have't noticed that!.

Comment: @Weszzz7 Read the UPDATE section in my answer, I have added a few more pointers for you.

Comment: @KirtiThorat Thanks for the update, things are looking quite good now except that they are still not being saved. I will update my original question with the latest output after implementing your changes.

Answer (score 3):

Your **`project_params`** should be like this

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, assets_attributes: [:image])
end
```

And also,why you are using **`protected`**? i guess you should be using **`private`**.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!
It still doesn't work however. Output from the project_params still only includes 'name' and 'description'. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Weszzz7 Can you post log information in the question please?

Comment: @Weszzz7 And also try using `private` instead of `protected`.

Comment: I added the request parameters to my question. Changing it to private hasn't changed a thing though :(

Comment: @Weszzz7 Your log info seems weird to me.There is no `asset params`.Try restarting the server and do with my suggested answer.

Comment: Changed the simple_form markup to default Rails form. Now the asset part is showing up in params. I will update my request parameters in the question.